# How can we estimate the combined causal effect of two separate parents in a Bayesian network?

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian-network, causal-diagram

Consider the following partially-defined Bayesian network:

[image]

- We know the probability of C given A is True and B is False
- We know the probability of C given A is False and B is True
- We know that C can only be true if at least one of A or B is True
- We do not know the probability of C given A and B are both True.

(To ground this in reality, in the field of medicine it is possible to study a population of people affected by disease A but not disease B to find the prevalence of feature C in this population. However, it may be very difficult to find a large enough sample size of people affected by both A and B to get a sense of the prevalence of C in that group. We therefore need to estimate this.

i.e. Asthma Attack might cause Cough in 40% of affected people, Bronchiolitis might cause Cough in 10% of affected people, so what is the probability of Cough in a person with both Asthma Attack and Bronchiolitis?)

Is there an established method to estimate $P(C \cap A \cap B)$ in this case?

Intuitively, it feels reasonable to imagine that in order for C to be False given both A and B are True, both A and B have to have individually FAILED to cause C. That is:

$P(C^\complement|A∩B) = P(C^\complement|A∩B^\complement)\times P(C^\complement|A^\complement∩B)$

Following this, we could estimate $P(C | A \cap B) = 0.46$

(This assumes that A and B do not have some positive or negative *synergistic effect* (is there a better term for this?) on C when both are True)

Are there other ways to make this estimate?